# Checking change in variable without making a copy

Tags: python, arrays, variables, copy

I have an iterative update algorithm (think gradient descent) where I stop the algorithm when the change in a variable `x` becomes less than some tolerance `tol`.

It looks like

```
def algorithm(x):
    for t in range(iterations):
        phi = update_phi(some_variables)

        temp = copy.deepcopy(x)
        x = update_x(x, phi)

        if dist(x,temp)<tol:
            break
```

Is there a more effective way to track the change without making a full copy? My `x` is very large (dimension in the millions) so I would rather not store an entire copy.

Thanks!

**Edit:** specifically the update is

```
def update_x(x, phi):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = const + np.sum(phi[i], axis = 0)
    return x
```

where `phi` is an 3-dimensional array (i.e. having shape `(n,m,l)`). The distance `dist(x,y)` is the Euclidean distance between vectors.

If we try to calculate the change *during* the update, it still comes down to the change in `phi`.

Comment: It would help to see the `update` code.  Could it compute `dist` as it goes and return that value along with `x`?

Comment: @Samwise good suggestion, added.